# How to calculate ray

Tags: analytic-geometry

In [ray-tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)) technique critical point is to calculate rays which came out from eye $E$ to target $T$ through pixel $P_{ij}$ on viewport. The "viewport" is represented as rectangle divided to square pixels - this rectangle is perpendicular to line which go through points $E$, $C$ (viewport center) and $T$. The ray (red line on image) is represented by point $E$ and unit  vector $r_{ij}$ (not shown in picture but it lay on red line) - below is picture which show "geometry" - but what are the formulas to calculate $r_{ij}$?

The given input values are:

- eye position $E$,
- target position $T$,
- field of view $\theta$ (angle, for human eye $\approx 90^\circ$),
- number of square pixels $k$ (horizontal direction) and $m$ (vertical direction).
- we also know vertical $w$ vector usually equal to $w=[wx,wy,wz]=[0,1,0]$ (not shown on picture) which indicate where is up and where is down

The orthogonal vectors $v$ and $b$  (and $t$) on picture are determined by $w$ and $t=T-E$ and maybe will useful in $r_{ij}$ calculations. The $d$ and pixel size is arbitrary and don't change the result because of fixed $\theta$.

**Question**: How to calculate unit vector $r_{ij}$ knowing input values described above?

[image]

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to know?

Comment: @amd I update question - now it is more clear?

Comment: This is described in almost all tutorials and books on the subject.

Comment: @lightxbulb In all sources that I know - there are similar description to above, but no explicite formulas

Comment: Scratchapixel, pbrt-book, ray tracing in one weekend are all free access, and all of those explain how this is done.

Comment: @lightxbulb I type in google your keywords (e.g. Scratchapixel) and find tons of text/codes to study/analyse  without actually direct answer to my question. The value of answer to this question will be proper formulas and short explanation.

Comment: Work backwards: to get a unit vector, you need _any_ vector that points in the correct direction; to get that, you need the coordinates of $P_{ij}$; and so on. Every one of these involves a simple operation that you could derive on your own or look up on Scratchapixel.

Comment: @amd yeach, but how to find $P_{ij}$ if you don't have coordinates of corners(and center)? It is not trivial - I have some Idea but I will wait for others

Answer (score 0):

**IDEA**: lets find position of center of each pixel $P_{ij}$ which allows us to easily find ray which starts at $E$ and go thought that pixel. To do it we find first $P_{1m}$ and find others by move on vievports plane.

**ASSUMPTION**: Below we introduce formulas which includes distance $d$ between eye and viewport however this value will be reduced during ray $r_{ij}$ normalization (so you might as well accept that $d=1$ and remove it from calculations).

**PRECALCULATIONS**: First we calculate normalized vectors $v_n, b_n$ from picutre (which are parallel to viewport plane and give as direction for shifting)

$$t = T-E, \qquad b = w\times t  $$

$$ 
t_n = \frac{t}{||t||}, \qquad
b_n = \frac{b}{||b||}, \qquad
v_n = t_n\times b_n \\ 
$$

notice: $C=E+t_nd$, then we calculate viewport size divided by 2 and including aspect ratio $\frac{m}{k}$

$$g_x=\frac{h_x}{2} =d \tan \frac{\theta}{2}, \qquad  g_y =\frac{h_y}{2} = g_x \frac{m}{k}$$

and then we calculate shifting vectors $q_x,q_y$ on viewport $x,y$ direction and viewport left upper pixel

$$ q_x = \frac{2g_x}{k-1}b_n, \qquad
q_y = \frac{2g_y}{m-1}v_n, \qquad
p_{1m} = t_n d - g_xb_n - g_yv_n$$

**CALCULATIONS**: notice that $P_{ij} = E + p_{ij}$ and ray $R_{ij} = P_{ij} -E = p_{ij}$ so normalized ray $r_{ij}$ is

$$ p_{ij} = p_{1m} + q_x(i-1) + q_y(j-1)$$
$$ r_{ij} = \frac{p_{ij}}{||p_{ij}||} $$

**TEST**: above formulas wast tested [here](https://kamil-kielczewski.github.io/fractals/mandelbulb.html) (works in browser)

**SUMMARY**: The above form is convenient to use it in shaders where in shader kernel we perform only final calculation based on prcarculated $q_x,q_y$ and $p_{1m}$. Wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)#Calculate_rays_for_rectangular_viewport).